# Broadcom Wifi not working in Ubuntu 17.04 in Dell Vostro-3446 laptop

Tags: wireless, dell, laptop, 17.04

Recently I installed Ubuntu 17.04 in my Dell laptop, but WiFi does not work in Ubuntu (It works well in windows 7). I have already tried the following steps, but no luck.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copied and pasted the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

then

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Output of `lspci -nn -d 14e4`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Output of `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: what's the output of  `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Answer (score 0):

It seams like you should install a chipset

try this first :

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

If it is still not working you may have your "secure boot" activated in your BIOS

reboot the computer and type delete several time (or f2 in some cases(should have a clue somewhere))

once in the BIOS find an option called "secure boot" and deactivate it

then save and reboot

if it still not working you may have a look to what is called "additional drivers" in your system settings->software sources

or try again

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

hope this help

Comment: If you reactivate Secure Boot, the driver will stop working.

Comment: After executing the command "sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source", wifi is working now for me. But I have tried the same command yesterday, but wifi was not working that time, not sure why its happened.